# iTunes My Music to Apple Music Artist link

Tags: itunes, music

searched and searched, and thought you guys might have the answer. I either can't find this feature or Apple hasn't included it in iTunes. It seems so clear to me that it should be part of iTunes somewhere that I'm convinced it's somewhere.

I want to be able to browse My Music library and be able to click a link such as "See Artist on Apple Music" this would bring me to the Apple Music page for that artist allowing me to add more albums of that particular artist. I can't seem to find anything like this other than having to search for that artist and selecting the tab "Apple Music" in the search box.

I'm hoping that something like this exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just noticed this message after it has been posted a long time ago, anyway here's my answer:

In iTunes artist view (top tab, 'My Music' selected and 'Artists' selected as grouping) select one artist on the sidebar on the left. There are three small tabs just below the artist name after you select one. If you click on 'All' it will show all music from that artist, including apple music (see screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot of iTunes, click on All (arrow) to see all music from that artist]